# Assign custom CSS class to an HTML element in custom template

Tags: magento-1.7, template, frontend, css

So I am overriding the cart template for bundle products. In short - there's this code in my `styles.css`:

```
.data-table tbody th,
.data-table tbody td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}
```

I changed the `#DDDDDD` to `red` just to be sure it's the correct one - it is. So I created another class underneath:

```
.bundle_option_cell {   vertical-align: middle;
      border: 0;
      border-bottom: 1px solid lime; 
}
```

and assigned this to a `<td>` tag but the change is not applied. The original settings (from the first class) apply. How can I force my changes?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about CSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think adding some HTML to the example might help, but assuming you have:

```
<table class="data-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="bundle_option_cell">This cell</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then CSS as follows should force the over-ride:

```
.data-table tbody th,
.data-table tbody td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}

.data-table tbody td.bundle_option_cell {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffff00;
}
```